# Expectation of a random variable.

Tags: random-variables, stochastic-analysis, variance

I am trying to calculate the variance of $\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} W(s) \,ds$. Assume $t_{2} \geq t_{1}>0$.

My approach so far has been,
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{Var}\left[\int_{t_1}^{t_2} W(s) \,ds\right] = \operatorname E\left[\left(\int_{t_1}^{t_2} W(s) \,ds\right)^2\right] \\[6pt]
= {} &\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} E[W(s) W(u)] \,du \,ds = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \min(s,u) \,du \,ds \\[6pt]
= {} &\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{t_1}^s u \,du \,ds + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_s^{t_2} s \,du \,ds \\[6pt]
= {} &\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{s^2}{2} - \frac{t_1^2}{2} \,ds + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} s(t_2-s) \,ds \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac{2t^3_1}{3} + \frac{t^3_2}{3} - t^2_1 t_2
\end{align}

This satisfies the various checks like,

1) If we let $t_{1} = 0$ and $t_{2} = t$ then we get $\frac{t^3}{3}.$

2) If we let $t_{1} = t$ and $t_{2} = t$ then we get $0$.

My question is - Is this the correct answer ? If it is, how do I prove the non-negativity of the variance?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you mean "How do I prove the nonnegativity of $\displaystyle \frac{2t^3_1}{3} + \frac{t^3_2}{3} - t^2_1 t_2$ when $t_2\ge t_1\ge 0,$?" then proving that the value of that expression is equal to the variance of some random variable does it. $\qquad$

Comment: The non-negative hypothesis on $t_1$ that @MichaelHardy added is necessary. Otherwise, the expression you obtained with $t_1=-10$ and $t_2=1$ is negative.

Comment: @Leandro : But usually in this sort of thing the domain of $W$ is taken to be $[0,\infty),$ and if that's been stated before then the hypothesis that I added explicitly is redundant. $\qquad$

Comment: That was my bad. t1, t2 are times so they have to be greater than zero. I should've been more careful. @michael - It's hard  for me to come up with one. I tried that approach. Then I tried factoring the expression too. There was a $t_{2} - 2t_{1}$ term there.

Comment: Yes I agree I was just emphasizing that the OP probably forgotten the hypothesis. In this case I guess that putting $t_2^3$ in evidence let clear that the expression is non-negative.

Comment: @Leandro I did not understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Hardy mentioned in comments the interesting question here is why the expression 
$$
\displaystyle \frac{2t^3_1}{3} + \frac{t^3_2}{3} - t^2_1 t_2
\geq 0,
$$
for all $0\leq t_1\leq t_2$. We can get the answer by the following arguent. First observe that 
$$
\displaystyle \frac{2t^3_1}{3} + \frac{t^3_2}{3} - t^2_1 t_2
=
t_2^3\left( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}\right)^3 -\left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}\right)^2 \right)
=
t_2^3\left( \frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}\right)^2
\left[\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}\right)-1\right] \right).
$$
Since $0\leq t_1/t_2\leq 1$, we can reduce the question to prove that $(1/3)+x^2((2/3)x-1)$ is non-negative for all $x\in [0,1]$. Note that we recover the expression in parenthesis by taking $x=t_1/t_2$. 
The minimum of the above polynomial can be computed explicitly by taking the derivative. One can see that the minimum is attained at x=1 and the minimum is zero. Since $t_2^3$ is non-negative the result follows.